# Specify format for rspec visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Now I'm doing `visit 'api/name'` in my rspec test. And getting answer in html-format. But I need json, something like `visit 'api/name', format: :json`.

Should I use another method?

I already have in controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: result.as_json }
    format.html do
            redirect_to '/'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: AFAIK capybara wasn't created for API testing. I'd rather use controller specs for that.

Answer (score -1):

Specify remote: true in your rails form. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have a form. It GET request for API. I doing it from rspec-file.